# No overload variant of "foo" of "Animal" matches argument type "str"

Tags: python, mypy, static-typing

I have a file `t.py` which has a class `Animal` and a subclass `Cat`. Both have the method `foo`, which has different return types based on the value of the boolean `inplace`.

Here's the file's compelte code:

```py
# t.py

from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TypeVar, Optional, overload, Literal 

CatOrDog = TypeVar("CatOrDog", bound="Animal")


class Animal:
    @overload
    def foo(self: CatOrDog, inplace: Literal[False], bar) -> CatOrDog:
        ...

    @overload
    def foo(self: CatOrDog, inplace: Literal[True], bar) -> None:
        ...

    def foo(
        self: CatOrDog, inplace: bool = False, bar=None
    ) -> Optional[CatOrDog]:
        ...

    def ffill(self) -> Optional[CatOrDog]:
        return self.foo(bar="a")


class Cat(Animal):
    @overload
    def foo(self, inplace: Literal[False], bar) -> Cat:
        ...

    @overload
    def foo(self, inplace: Literal[True], bar) -> None:
        ...

    def foo(self, inplace: bool = False, bar=None) -> Optional[Cat]:
        ...
```

If I run `mypy` on it, I get

```
$ mypy t.py 
t.py:23: error: No overload variant of "foo" of "Animal" matches argument type "str"
t.py:23: note: Possible overload variants:
t.py:23: note:     def foo(self, inplace: Literal[False], bar: Any) -> Animal
t.py:23: note:     def foo(self, inplace: Literal[True], bar: Any) -> None
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How can I properly overload `foo`, so that I can call `self.foo(bar="a")`? I have tried setting `bar: Any`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow default arguments for one of the overloads, and also set the correct type for `self` in the `ffill` method.

As:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TypeVar, Optional, overload, Literal 

CatOrDog = TypeVar("CatOrDog", bound="Animal")


class Animal:
    @overload
    def foo(self: CatOrDog, inplace: Literal[False]=..., bar=...) -> CatOrDog:
        ...

    @overload
    def foo(self: CatOrDog, inplace: Literal[True], bar=...) -> None:
        ...

    def foo(
        self: CatOrDog, inplace: bool = False, bar=None
    ) -> Optional[CatOrDog]:
        ...

    def ffill(self: CatOrDog) -> Optional[CatOrDog]:
        
        return self.foo(bar="a")


class Cat(Animal):
    @overload
    def foo(self, inplace: Literal[False]=..., bar=...) -> Cat:
        ...

    @overload
    def foo(self, inplace: Literal[True], bar=...) -> None:
        ...

    def foo(self, inplace: bool = False, bar=None) -> Optional[Cat]:
        ...
```

See https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=49da369f6343543769eed2060fa61639

Comment: Thanks @sebastian-kreft - in the `Literal[True]` overload, I don't need `bar=...`, right? I only need `=...` in one of the two overloads?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity you still need `bar=...` in the `Literal[True]` case, as `bar` is optional. If you don't specify it, then self.foo(True) would have the most generic typings.

Comment: what if `bar=None` came before `inplace=False` in the definition? Then I couldn't have `bar=..., inplace: Literal[True]` as a non-default would be following a default