# Overload method and call super

Tags: python, mypy, static-typing

I have a class `Animal` with a method `foo`, whose return type depends on the value of `inplace`.

Likewise, for the subclass `Cat`.

So far, so good. But, if I call `super().foo` in `Cat`, I get an error.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Optional, overload, Literal, TypeVar

CatOrDog = TypeVar('CatOrDog', bound='Animal')


class Animal:

    @overload
    def foo(self: CatOrDog, inplace: Literal[False]=...) -> CatOrDog: ...

    @overload
    def foo(self: CatOrDog, inplace: Literal[True]) -> None: ...

    def foo(
        self: CatOrDog, inplace: bool = False
    ) -> Optional[CatOrDog]:
        ...


class Cat(Animal):

    @overload
    def foo(self, inplace: Literal[False]=...) -> Cat: ...

    @overload
    def foo(self, inplace: Literal[True]) -> None: ...

    def foo(self, inplace: bool = False):
        return super().foo(inplace=inplace)
```

```
main.py:31: error: No overload variant of "foo" of "Animal" matches argument type "bool"
main.py:31: note: Possible overload variants:
main.py:31: note:     def foo(self, inplace: Literal[False] = ...) -> Cat
main.py:31: note:     def foo(self, inplace: Literal[True]) -> None
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=49da369f6343543769eed2060fa61639

I don't understand why it would fail - `Animal` does have an overload variant of `foo` which matches argument type `bool`.

Comment: Note that you *don't* have an overload variant with `inplace: bool` - the third definition of the method isn't an overload, it's the runtime implementation and is ignored by the type-checker.

Comment: Legend @jonrsharpe, that solves it, thanks!

Comment: Is there really a need to ask this [each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66426460/no-overload-variant-of-foo-of-animal-matches-argument-type-str) [day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66435480/overload-following-optional-argument) with only a micro step advancement? Surely there is some practical case you want to *solve* – why not ask about that?

Comment: The practical case is too large to fit in to a small self-contained reproducible example. Is it really necessary to post such snarky comments?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity It was not meant as snark, but an honest inquiry. Incremental, too specific questions can restrict possible answers and accidentally guide you to a less than optimal solution. Of course, at the end of the day you are the only one who can decide whether the questions are worth it or not.